# Smooth scrolling issues on web (using Angularjs)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

can anyone explain me, why my webpage have scrolling issues on mac safari? Same is on ipad: chrome & safari apps crashes on scrolling. Otherwise chrome at mac havn't got this issue: it looks like everything working perfect here.
web: http://tailorshop.tk/dist/

This is scrolling directive:

```
.directive('scrollOnClick', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      var mainbody = $("body");
      var idToScroll = attrs.href;
      element.on('click', function() {
        var $target;
        if (idToScroll) {
          $target = $(idToScroll);
        } else {
          $target = element;
        }
        mainbody.animate({scrollTop: $target.offset().top}, "slow");
      });
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: I tried on Mac OS X 10.10.4 in Safari and it didn't crash for me.

Comment: did you tried click menu items?

Comment: I'll look again tonight on the mac.

Comment: thank you. please let me know if you will find something

Comment: I see it's a little choppy on Safari but not much.  What libraries is your site using to do the scroll animations on click? Is it ng-animate or some other library?

Comment: I just add a script witch I found at stackoverflow, i'm placing code on main post

Answer (score 0):

When trying to animate scrolls, instead of `var mainbody = $("body");` use `var mainbody = $("html, body");` - if i remember correctly on some safari versions scroll animations doesnt work if you will apply it only for body, you need add it to html too.